# Create Php variable using for

Tags: php

This is my php code:

```
$text1 = "text 1";
$text2 = "text 2";
$text3 = "text 3";
  for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){

     echo "<script>alert('$text1');</script>";
  }
```

In here I want to create $text1, $text2 ... variables automatically using for but when I replace the **$text1** with **$text.$i** php fetchs **$text** + **$i** me individually. How can I do this?

Comment: use arrays instead.

Comment: I know it but I don't want to use array.

Comment: Then you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${'text'.$i}` to print them in the for.

Answer (score 0):

You  should use an  array

```
$text[0] = "text 0";
$text[1] = "text 1";
$text[2] = "text 2";  

foreach ($text as $key => $value){

    echo "<script>alert('".  $value. "');</script>";
}
```

or use the `{ 'string' . $cnt }` construct

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not the best way to do it, i would suggest using an Array.

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        'text1' => "Text 1",
        'text2' => "Text 2",
        'text3' => "Text 3",
    )

    for($array AS $key => $value) {
        echo "<script>alert('$value');</script>";
    }
?>
```

However, in PHP it is possible to call a variable inside a string. So you could do something like that.

```
<?php
    $text1 = "text 1";
    $text2 = "text 2";
    $text3 = "text 3";
    for($i = 1; $i <= 3 ; $i ++) {
         $value = "text" . $i;
         echo "<script>alert(" . $$value . ");</script>";
    }
?>
```

Hope it helps !

- Nic

Comment: I know it but I don't want to use array.

Comment: @FoeMartist Then you can use the second method.